# X710 and mlx5_core together on same server

Tags: intel, mellanox

I have a amd server with centos 7.9
I am trying to using the the kernel driver for 2 cards:

1. Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572 --> i40e
2. MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5] 1017' --> mlx5_core

For mellanox i used:

- /usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64/weak-updates/mlnx-ofa_kernel/drivers/base/auxiliary.ko
- /usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64/weak-updates/mlnx-ofa_kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core/mlx5_core.ko

If i try to load mellanox auxiliary i get the following error because i40e auxiliary is already loaded ( it happens also with i40e if mellanox auxiliary is already loaded)

```
insmod /usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64/weak-updates/mlnx-ofa_kernel/drivers/base/auxiliary.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64/weak-updates/mlnx-ofa_kernel/drivers/base/auxiliary.ko: File exists
```

And if i try to load the mlx5_core i get the following errors

```
mlx5_core: disagrees about version of symbol auxiliary_device_init
mlx5_core: Unknown symbol auxiliary_device_init (err -22)
mlx5_core: disagrees about version of symbol auxiliary_driver_unregister
mlx5_core: Unknown symbol auxiliary_driver_unregister (err -22)
```

Can they work together?

Each one of them succeeded to work seperatly with the auxiliary.ko that arrive with the driver

It happens only from i40e version 2.17.15 - perhaps due to change "Add RDMA auxilary bus submodule support".
In  2.17.4 it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this exact same issue myself.  Did you find a work around for it?  Would prefer not to have to edit the driver build to rename the .ko modules, but that is likely the solution.

Comment: Renaming the intel .ko to int_auxiliary.ko seems to fix the issue, but that requires a lot of editing.... Intel.... why did you do this??  I am going to file a case with Intel so see if the next round they can fix this, I would prefer not to need to support moving all these edits forward.

Comment: My workaround was to go to the previous version, since I don't need that latest version updates. But if you could put here the changes you did to fix it, would be great. And also a link to the ticket you opened to intel so I can follow it also.